# Why is keyboard and mouse unable to be hotplugged in FreeBSD jail?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, jails

I have an entire system with xorg-x11 running in a jail.  My only issue is that I am unable to add or remove a keyboard or mouse while X is running.  If I restart X, the newly connected keyboard or mouse works just fine.  I don't want to restart X.  If I run my system on bare metal, it works as expected.  It only occurs when I run it from a jail.

I see the devices are created as I plug or unplug them:

```
/dev/input/event*
/dev/usb/*
/dev/ukbd*
/dev/kbd*
/dev/ums*
/dev/ugen*
```

I have dbus running, but for whatever reason, Xorg doesn't appear to be seeing them.

If I tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log, I don't see any messages indicating a keyboard or mouse being added or removed as I plug or unplug it.

EDIT #1:

My devfs rules for this jail are:

```
add path 'dri*' unhide
add path 'drm*' unhide
add path 'dsp*' unhide
add path 'mixer*' unhide

add path 'speaker*' mode 0660 group operator unhide

# USB drives
add path 'da*' unhide
```